# Passing a WeakValueDictionary namespace to exec

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to better understand the behavior I am observing with the `exec` function.

The `exec` function disallows use of non-dict types for the namespace mapping arguments (`globals`, `locals`). Example:

```
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary as wdict

# dummy object to put in the wdict since wdict can't hold references to 
# most built-in types:
a = type('dummy', (), {})() 
exec('print(a)', wdict(a = a)) # TypeError: exec() globals must be a dict, not wdict
```

That's not a problem; we'll just get around that by making a weak dictionary that is also a `dict`:

```
mydict = type('mydict', (wdict, dict), {})

m = mydict(a = a)
list(m) # ['a'] <-- entry for dummy() object
```

The `mydict` works as expected...

```
del a
import gc
gc.collect() # force garbage collection and mydict/wdict update
list(m) # [] <--- entry for the dummy() object removed as expected
```

So we can now pass a `mydict` as the globals namespace of `exec`:

```
a = type('dummy', (), {})()
m = mydict(a = a)
exec('print(a)', m) # dummy object printed as expected
```

Given the above, it appears any new objects added to a `mydict` namespace- that is, anything global created in our code block- will be ephemeral (weak references created only and therefore subject to garbage collection):

```
exec('test = type("test", (), {})', m)
gc.collect()
test = m['test'] # KeyError: 'test'
```

This is potentially a useful situation. For example, say I want to create an interactive code session in which the user cannot create any permanent objects in the provided namespace (e.g., administering a test to students), but they CAN update/change existing objects:

```
code = sanitized_input_file('somefile.py')
examine_code(code)
namespace = mydict(a = InterestingObject1(), b = InterestingObject2())
exec(code, namespace)
gc.collect()
examine_namespace(namespace)
```

Of course this is somewhat limited since user cannot add temporary references to many built-in objects, e.g. `int`, to a `mydict`. But this can be gotten around by providing my own set of built-ins to the globals namespace as thin wrappers around the native ones.

Also worth noting: as usual, we can still capture expressions using `eval` or `compile`:

```
test = eval('type("test", (), dict(a = a)))', m)
```

...and any concrete references created in the namespace are preserved:

```
del a
gc.collect()
print(test.a) # dummy object reference still exists
```

My question is: is my understanding of this behavior- the ephemeral nature of objects added to my weakly held namespace- correct? Can I be certain that newly created objects in the namespace do not persist? What pitfalls should I be aware of if I am going to try to leverage this to accomplish interesting things?

Comment: Yeesh. I would not rely on that; you have no idea when some part of the code will bypass the WeakValueDictionary part of your object and start making direct PyDict_GetItem and PyDict_SetItem calls.

Comment: @user2357112 Good point, but I could bypass the `__getattr__` of the `mydict` class object with a metaclass to restrict access to the `dict` class methods, and prevent doing something like `dict.__setitem__(globals(), 'new_key', evil_item)` with my own built-ins...

Comment: I was thinking of the C API calls, which wouldn't be affected by such a metaclass. For example, it looks like if your `exec`uted code contains a `global x` declaration, stores to x will use PyDict_SetItem.

Comment: @user2357112 I did not realize that. And do not know much about making C API calls, but that would certainly throw a wrench into things. Great input.

Comment: @RickTeachey I'd also not depend on GC happening instantly. Technically it seems like the weakref tools might make it easy to assume this is done immediately but GC stuff rarely does (in the non-Python-specific general sense).